# RetryOperationsInterceptor - Requeue at queue's tail

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm using RetryOperationsInterceptor. Every time a message consumption throws an exception, the message is put back in the queue. That's what I want, but I want it at the tail of the queue instead of the head. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to republish it to the queue in the recoverer.

Add a `RepublishMessageRecoverer` to the interceptor.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-listeners

It will still retry immediately, so you would have to set maxAttempts to 1 and use a message header to count how many delivery attempts have been made, so you will probably need to customize the recoverer.